# Sybase + how to compute sequence number for a speicific group

Tags: sybase

```
Date      column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
01-Jan-17 A       AB      10      AB_1    10
02-Jan-17 B       AB      20      AB_2    10
03-Jan-17 C       AB      30      AB_3    10
04-Jan-17 D       AB      20      AB_4    -10
05-Jan-17 E       AB      40      AB_5    20
06-Jan-17 X       GH      30      GH_1    30
07-Jan-17 V       GH      40      GH_2    10
08-Jan-17 A       GH      50      GH_3    10
```

Requirement1 :For all the columns having same value in column2, the column4 should be numbered sequentially

Requirement2:For all the columns having same value in column2, the column5 should be computed  as current value of column3 - previous value of column3

Appreciate your help!!

I'm using Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 22234 SMP SP121 /P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux/ase157sp12x/3660/64-bit/FBO/

Comment: what query(s) have you tried so far? which Sybase product (ASE, SQLAnywhere, IQ, Advantage) and what version?

Comment: what do you want to do with the data? update the table? or just run a select that would sort the rows?

Comment: it looks (to me) like the data you've posted is the desired result set; if this is the case ... what does the original data look like? I suggest you take a look at [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then come back and update your question with the details necessary to clarify what it is you're attempting to do

Comment: Thanks for the response !! @markup I'm using Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7

Comment: @AdamLeszczyński The columns 4 and 5 are required to be updated in a table while the other columns are readily available from other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with multi-step processing as follows (I didn;t test it, but you'll get the idea). Assuming your table is named 't'.

```
select your_date, column1, column2, column3, id = identity(9) into #t1 from t order by column2, column3  -- this seems to be the ordering you want?

select column2, min(id) as min_id into #t2 from #t1 group by column2

select #t1.* column4 = (#t1.id - #t2.min_id + 1) into #t3 from #t1, #t2 where #t2.column2 = #t1.column2

select ta.*, column5 = case when tb.id is null or tb.column2 <> ta.column2 then ta.column3 else ta.column3 - tb.column3 from #t3 ta, #t1 tb where ta.id *= (tb.id - 1)
```

Comment: Awesome @RobV !!!! Actually it can be narrowed down further by using the seq_no = id - (select min(id) from #t2 where tv2.column2= tv1.column2) +1   Also the last sql is not working, instead I had used and  (t2.seq_no-t1.seq_no) = 1  ..Overall your idea is great!!! Really Appreciated !!!!